# GetItems() filtering Archived items

Tags: c#, xero-api

Finding my around Xero API. Using the Xero .NetStandard library and getting a little stuck with what I thought would be quite a simple thing so pretty sure I'm missing something.

Trying to get a list of Items from a particular tenant using the follow code.

```
string whereFilter = "IsSold==True";
var xeroApi = new Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Api.AccountingApi();
var response = await xeroApi.GetItemsAsync(<AccessToken>, <TenantId>, null, whereFilter);
```

Where I'm getting stuck is I can't for the life of me figure out how to filter out items that have been marked as Archived.  What am I missing?